# Java Hibernate - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm just trying to get the object `TestFlow` from the database that has FK `TestCase` and `TestCase` has FK `TestType`.

I'm getting this error when loading the `TestFlow` object from db.

I basically have `lazy = false` in every many-to-one like this:

```
 <many-to-one name="testCase" class="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase" column="testCase" fetch="select" cascade="all" lazy="false"/>
```

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType.testCases, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType.testCases, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestFlow["testCase"]->com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase["type"]->com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType["testCases"])

Can someone explain me what this is and how to fix it? **Do you need aditional code for me to post?**

Edit: If I remove `lazy = false` I get

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestFlow["testCase"]->com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase_$$_jvst887_5["name"])

Fetching the TestFlow:

```
public static List<TestFlow> getFlow(String testFlowName) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
    Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<TestFlow> testFlows = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        testFlows = hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM TestFlow WHERE name= :testFlowName").setParameter("testFlowName",testFlowName).list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.close();
    }

    return testFlows;
}
```

Comment: How is the mapping of the `many-to-one` relation of the TestType class defined?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hzg40d is this what you need?

Comment: post the code of the method that does the query.. also point the transaction boundaries

Comment: Edited: Without lazy = false debug print -> http://prntscr.com/hzg82d

Comment: The Jackson library's Hibernate lazy-loading is currently broken. You have to manually walk through every child object that you need loaded before passing it all to Jackson.

Comment: And how is the mapping for `TestType` defined?

Comment: Add the relevant mapping (TestCase, TestType.. etc) also ManyToOne are by default eager

Comment: how do I remove eager?

Comment: that means specifying lazy= false is the same as not writing anything